# In excel how do I dynamically sum a column from a different sheet based on multiple criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Down below is an example of the workbook I am working on. Where I need the help is I want to look up and sum the values for person 1 in the variance sheet dependent on the month and the department. Each department is a different sheet.

I was at first thinking of using an indirect or index and match. I not sure which would be better.
I also could use some help with the formula.

Variance Sheet

|  | 4/1/23 |  |  | 5/1/23 |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | Actual | Budget | Variance | Actual | Budget | Variance |
| -------- | -------- | -------- | -------- | -------- | -------- | -------- |
| Department 1 |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| -------- | -------- | -------- | -------- | -------- | -------- | -------- |
| Person 1 | Cell 1 | Cell 2 | Cell 3 | Cell 4 | Cell 5 | Cell 6 |
| Person 2 | Cell 1 | Cell 2 | Cell 3 | Cell 4 | Cell 5 | Cell 6 |
| Person 3 | Cell 1 | Cell 2 | Cell 3 | Cell 4 | Cell 5 | Cell 6 |
| Person 4 | Cell 1 | Cell 2 | Cell 3 | Cell 4 | Cell 5 | Cell 6 |
|  | 4/1/23 |  |  | 5/1/23 |  |  |
|  | Actual | Budget | Variance | Actual | Budget | Variance |
| -------- | -------- | -------- | -------- | -------- | -------- | -------- |
| Department 2 |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| -------- | -------- | -------- | -------- | -------- | -------- | -------- |
| Person 1 | Cell 1 | Cell 2 | Cell 3 | Cell 4 | Cell 5 | Cell 6 |
| Person 2 | Cell 1 | Cell 2 | Cell 3 | Cell 4 | Cell 5 | Cell 6 |
| Person 3 | Cell 1 | Cell 2 | Cell 3 | Cell 4 | Cell 5 | Cell 6 |
| Person 4 | Cell 1 | Cell 2 | Cell 3 | Cell 4 | Cell 5 | Cell 6 |
|  | 4/1/23 |  |  | 5/1/23 |  |  |
|  | Actual | Budget | Variance | Actual | Budget | Variance |
| -------- | -------- | -------- | -------- | -------- | -------- | -------- |
| Department 3 |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| -------- | -------- | -------- | -------- | -------- | -------- | -------- |
| Person 1 | Cell 1 | Cell 2 | Cell 3 | Cell 4 | Cell 5 | Cell 6 |
| Person 2 | Cell 1 | Cell 2 | Cell 3 | Cell 4 | Cell 5 | Cell 6 |
| Person 3 | Cell 1 | Cell 2 | Cell 3 | Cell 4 | Cell 5 | Cell 6 |
| Person 4 | Cell 1 | Cell 2 | Cell 3 | Cell 4 | Cell 5 | Cell 6 |

Department 1 Sheet

| Department 1 |
| --- |
| -------- | April | June |
| Account 1 | Cell 1 | Cell 3 |
| Account 2 | Cell 1 | Cell 3 |
| Account 1 | Cell 1 | Cell 3 |
| Account 2 | Cell 1 | Cell 3 |

Department 2 Sheet

| Department 2 |
| --- |
| -------- | April | June |
| Account 1 | Cell 1 | Cell 3 |
| Account 2 | Cell 1 | Cell 3 |
| Account 1 | Cell 1 | Cell 3 |
| Account 2 | Cell 1 | Cell 3 |

Department 3 Sheet

| Department 1 |
| --- |
| -------- | April | June |
| Account 1 | Cell 1 | Cell 3 |
| Account 2 | Cell 1 | Cell 3 |
| Account 1 | Cell 1 | Cell 3 |
| Account 2 | Cell 1 | Cell 3 |

At first I was using a sumif (See Below) How ever I realized this is not dynamic enough for my needs

D1 is the department sheet. I is the Apr column. Both these values will change depending on the cell.

Variance is the sheet Where this is going and F12 is the person I am looking up

```
=SUMIF('D1'!$G:$G,Variance!$F12,'D1'!I:I)
```

Comment: Your formula shows different Sheet names than the ones refered as in your post. What is the Sheet you have and what do you want to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

Indirect is your best option if you are sure that cells are always the same.

**Your problem:**

- There are multiple sheets and you need to calculate the actual budget of each "Person" per month.

*note:*
INDEX:MATCH will work, however, if the person has more than one row, your best choice is IF:ARRAY.

> =SUM(IF('Department 1'!$A$2:$A$20=MAIN!$A3,
> IF('Department 1'!$C$1:$D$1=MAIN!B$1,'Department 1'!$C$2:$D$20)))

- Code above will first match the Person from Column A, then your next IF clause is to match the DATE from Rows of DATEs. Then the range of the values. Then wrap with "SUM" function.

If you have like many sheets. i.e being added every week or N times in a month. Indirect is your best bet to lessen your editing time.

[Main page referencing other sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YMSFd.png)

[Department 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k4tKL.png)